# Email actions for localized multi-language emails

Tags: email, localization, google-schemas

I want to use Action Buttons in an email that is localized to around 20 different languages.

Do I need to submit samples and register each localized version of the email? Or just the one 'master' version (which is in English).

Many thanks

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to submit one whitelisting request (in English) if the email content is the same, but localized in different languages, and all emails are sent by the same static email address.